# Sull'uso del verbo "riscontrare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Ho cercato il significato di "riscontrare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono sicura di saper usare questo vocabolo correttamente.  In concreto, la mia domanda è: si può adoperare questo verbo come sinonimo di "trovare"? Ecco alcuni esempi di frasi in cui l'ho usato con l'intenzione di esprimere tale senso:

> Non ho l'impressione di aver riscontrato difficoltà particolari in questi compiti.
>
> Ho studiato l'italiano da autodidatta, ma non ho riscontrato nessuna difficoltà a superare l'esame per ottenere il certificato di livello B2.

Sono corrette? E se sono corrette, in quale registro linguistico sarebbe considerato naturale usarle?

Nel [dizionario dei Sinonimi e Contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riscontrare_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) ho visto "trovare" tra i sinonimi di "riscontrare", ma non sono sicura che mi sfugga qualche sfumatura.

**Aggiornamento:** 
Forse il problema è che questi esempi non corrispondono ai contesti più adatti per usare questo verbo, a meno che non voglia sembrare una pedante o parlare come i politici. Ma ecco un esempio che ho trovato nel libro *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* (Loescher Editore, Torino, 2013), in una sezione in cui si elenca il lessico da usare per presentare e commentare dati statistici:

> - **Si riscontrano** differenze evidenti in tutti i settori.
> - **Si rileva** / **Si registra** una differenza tra lavoratori e studenti.

Ho messo anche questi esempi con i verbi "rilevare" e "registrare" perché mi sembrano molto simili a "riscontrare". Quindi, immagino che il contesto adatto per usare questo verbo sia un racconto di tipo tecnico nel quale sia necessario usare molti sinonimi per non ripetere eccessivamente gli stessi verbi come, per l'appunto, la presentazione di dati statistici. È così?

Comment: Tipica parola “burocratica”; nel primo caso *trovato* va benissimo, nel secondo *avuto*.

Comment: @egreg: Quindi si tratta di un verbo da usare soltanto in un registro molto formale? Cioè, sarebbe naturale usare questo tipo di frasi se scrivendo un curriculum vitae, ma se sto facendo un corso e dico queste cose a un compagno di classe, questo potrebbe pensare che sono una pedante?

Comment: Concordo con @egreg: è uno di quei “quasi-sinonimi” che fanno sentire più importante chi li usa, come “recarsi” al posto di “andare”, “conferire” al posto di “portare” etc., più tutti quelli con un po' di sillabe inutili (“modalità” per “modo”, “problematica” per “problema”, “tipologia” per “tipo”...).

Comment: @DaG: Vocaboli tanto amati dai politici, perlomeno nel mio paese. Adesso i rappresentanti comunali di Barcellona dicono persino cose come "arbrat" invece di "arbres" ("alberi") o "semaforització" (parola molto facile da pronunciare) invece di "semàfors" ("semafori").

Comment: @Charo: Tutto il mondo è paese, mi sa...

Answer (score 1):

Nella mia esperienza riscontrare si usa nei casi in cui si vuole sottolineare un evento inatteso:

"Ho riscontrato delle difficoltà" vuol dire che quelle difficoltà non erano previste dall'inizio, mentre trovato va a prendere un significato più neutro.

Answer (score 0):

Il thread dei commenti fornisce già un po' di risposte.

Personalmente credo ci sia una sottigliezza di significato (nota bene: questa è la mia interpretazione, potrei sbagliarmi):

*Trovare* ha un significato neutro. Puoi trovare una prova a sostegno o contro di qualcosa.

*Riscontrare* tendenzialmente ha un significato positivo. Riscontri qualcosa che sostiene una tesi.

Nei due esempi che hai menzionato, abbiamo:

*Non ho l'impressione di aver riscontrato difficoltà particolari in questi compiti.* -> La tesi è che i compiti in questione siano difficili, ma non ho trovato prove a favore di questa tesi.

*Ho studiato l'italiano da autodidatta, ma non ho riscontrato nessuna difficoltà a superare l'esame per ottenere il certificato di livello B2.* -> La tesi è che l'esame di livello B2 sia di una difficoltà tale da penalizzare gli autodidatti rispetto a chi riceve un'istruzione formale, ma nel mio caso non ho prove a riguardo (anzi, se mai il mio caso è una disputa della tesi!).

Ripeto: questa è la mia interpretazione del termine. Potrei sbagliarmi.